# Tying reducers and actions to a non-root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Background**

I have one and a half years' experience with Angular 1.x, moving to React/Redux for a project that Angular is ill suited for. I've read somewhere that React is "basically all directives" from Angular, which is fantastic, because I think directives are Angular's strongest feature. However, the mentality of creating an app in React/Redux versus Angular is also very different (like the idea of creating the data backbone and then representing it, versus Angular's less centralized approach). There's something I'm having a lot of trouble understanding.

**The setup**

The application is being written in Electron, using the following as a sapling: https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

My root reducer looks something like this:

```
root: {
  Home: Object, // Basic homepage tab
  Gallery: [ // Gallery tab
    { // A single instance of "photo" object
      filename: String,
      metadata: Object,
      error: Object
    }
  ]
}
```

The Gallery has a function to open a directory. It scans the user-selected directory and looks for photos there, receiving an array of filenames. Then it is supposed to render every photo as a component, and each photo, upon being initialized with the filename, should initiate its own process of reading the picture metadata and rendering its own info on the page.

I got it to the point where I can render all the filenames on the page no problem. However, I need the filenames to transform into rendered and processed photos. That's where I'm having trouble.

**The issue**

The photo has a few properties, as can be seen in the bit above. It also has a few actions (e.g. `new`, `update`, `delete`, etc). The properties and actions need to be tied to the component. Normally, with page-sized components, this is done in a JS file which does all the `connect` and `bindActionCreators` calls. This JS file is then included in a react router, and presented as a page.

Photos are not pages. They're meant to be reusable components of which there are lots on the page. How do I properly attach all the properties and actions of a photo to it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may be getting your wires crossed on models/action/reducers. Unlike Angular and other frameworks, your model should be "dumb" in that it's just data; your `Gallery` or `Photo` objects shouldn't have methods. Rather, your view fires actions, which your reducer uses to update the store (which holds the model), which is then read and pushed back into the view. Unlike MVVM (MVV*?), your model (store state) does not have to mimic the structure of your components; rather, it just maintains pure data. So having a `Home` and `Gallery` property might not make sense.

Let's reimagine your reducer like this:

```
const initialState = {
  photos: []
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DELETE_PHOTO':
      return { 
        photos: state.photos.filter(photo => photo.filename !== action.payload.filename) 
      };
    // etc.
  }

  return state;
}
```

Now your view could be something like this:

```
import deletePhoto from '../actionCreators/deletePhoto';

function Photo({ filename, onDelete }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={filename}/>
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(filename)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function PhotoGallery({ photos, deletePhoto }) {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      photos.map(photo => <Photo filename={photo.filename} onDelete={deletePhoto}/>);
    }
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ photos: state.photos });
const mapActionsToProps = { deletePhoto };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(PhotoGallery);
```

...then your action creator `deletePhoto` could be something like:

```
export default function deletePhoto(filename) {
  return { type: 'DELETE_PHOTO', payload: { filename } };
}
```

Breaking down your reducer into more granular pieces is recommended, but instead of doing that by augmenting your model, you can use something like [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html).

I'd suggest you try to unlearn MVVM and really understand the flux pattern. I'm not saying it's a better pattern, but you'll really be going against the grain if you try to use a different pattern with redux.